# Adding both Delay + Bandwidth restrictions via TC

Tags: linux, networking, bandwidth, traffic

I'm trying to set both delay + bandwidth to tc. However I can't add two rules without running into.

```
Error: Exclusivity flag on, cannot modify.
```

I want both:

```
tc qdisc add dev enp5s0f0 root tbf rate 102mbit latency 10000ms burst 102mbit
tc qdisc add dev enp5s0f0 root netem delay 20ms
```

Is there a way I can channel them together in one rule?
Or a way to enforce both rules somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently netem also now offers the rate parameter.

```
sudo tc qdisc add dev enp5s0f0 root netem delay 20ms rate 100mbit
```